# Null Reference Exception with .GetValueNames() method

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I am trying to get all the instance names of SQL on a machine, all the values are held in a regkey here is my code, but I keep getting a null reference exception.

```
private void RegLoop()
{
     RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL")
      foreach (var v in key.GetValueNames())
      {
         MessageBox.Show("{0}", v);
      }
}
```

Comment: You have two spaces in `Microsoft  SQL Server` - is that intentional?

Comment: yes the key path is right, but is it maybe because of the first value name is (Default)?  would that mess it up?

Comment: Now i see what you are talking about, that is just from the copy and past, my acutal code does not contain that.  good eye.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)

Comment: Copy/Past does not add spaces. This is from _not_ using Copy/Paste, and that often leads to waste of time.

Comment: the code editor on this site always re formats the layout of the my code.  i wasn't talking about the copy and past from my IDE into here, but i do a lot of copy and pasting to get my code readable on this site.  sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you receive that exception, it means that `key` contains a `null` value. Therefore, the `OpenSubKey()` method did not return anything, likely because what you're searching for cannot be found.

Comment: Radu is right, it was looking in the wrong place, due to the WOW6432Node, the key im looking at exists in the default location, not in the WOW6432Node